# How to display large data tables using plain html or php mysql or any other

Tags: database-design, database-table

I want to make a site of baby names. How do i display the baby name tables. using plain HTML and CSS or using PHP MYSQL tables or there is any other way or technology and which one loads faster.

And how to make each name in a table as a link which takes to a page displaying the name meaning. How to make each name of more than 20,000 as a link by manually or there is any other short way.

Comment: And if you don't want to be down-voted terribly I would rewrite this question ASAP.

Comment: Sure u can re write the question for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot of questions in one!  I can't really answer them all for you, but I'll try and explain a couple things and let you know that I think it would be smarter for you to research thoroughly your questions and if you can't find an answer, resubmit all of your questions more formally one at a time if you really want good answers.

Using plain HTML will require that you edit the HTML directly each time you want to add or remove a new entry, usually a person would want to create a program to add or edit entries more easily.  Depending on how involved you want to get in programming you could build something from scratch or use an established CRM.

What technology or method loads the fastest depends less on the technology you use and more on how effectively you use the programming language, database, and data.  Assuming you want to use web based technologies, you have so many choices:

You could build a very traditional Apache server (LAMP/WAMP stack) using 
Linux, Apache2, MySQL, and PHP and you would use PHP and MySQL to generate your tables and present them in HTML.

You could build a tool entirely front-end with Javascript/HTML/CSS you'll still need a web server, and a central place to store the data.

You could play around with node.js and build a web app that uses Javascript on the backend as well as the front end.

I guess the summary is that you could use any number of programming languages on a web server to manipulate, store, retrieve your data.  It sounds like you have a lot of questions; low level questions and high level questions.  If I were you I would just take one question at a time and get a good answer.  And instead of asking which technologies are better, use what you know and learn what you don't. There are too many ways to do what you're asking to provide a good answer to your many questions.